# I wanted to know how can I do get response and post response using ajax and jquery on jsp servlet web project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I wanted to know how can i do a get and post from a servlet and use jquery ajax i.e. in the jsp page to get response and post it .I have done doget .Also if possible I want to remove jstl from my jsp page.Please help me .And thanks in advance

Here is my controller class

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //get the data from database ie the model class
    try {
        List<Script> scriptitems=modelDBUtil.getScriptList();
        request.setAttribute("scriptItems", scriptitems);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*String itemsfood[]={"biriyani","rice"};
    request.setAttribute("itemsfood",itemsfood)*/;



    //redirect to a different page
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("scriptviewer.jsp");

    dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
  }

}

}
```

Now my jsp page please help me here

```
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Menu</title>
    </head>
<body>
<p>Script Items</p>

<c:forEach var="items" items="${scriptItems}">


    ${items.id} ${items.command}
</c:forEach>
<form action="appendfile.jsp" method="post">
    <select name="department">
          <c:forEach var="item" items="${scriptItems}">
            <option value="${item.id}">${item.command}</option>
          </c:forEach>
       </select>
       <button type="submit" id="idsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question and code is not clear. What you are asking? can you explain bit more what are you trying to say? Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have edited it ...now

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can send json from JSP to Servlete please refer this code 
with comments

```
  $("#mForm").submit(function(e) {  //your form ID chane it here 
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        if (!$form.valid()) return false;

        var url = "yourServeleteName";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", //the method you want invoke 
          url: "yourServeleteName",  //Add here your servelete name
          data: $("#mForm").serialize(),  //your form ID remove default action from your form
          success: function (data)  //This is to handle if you want any response from Servlete
          {
            alert(data);  //it will alret you message you send from servelete
            //$("#mForm")[0].reset();  /if any form you can reset it option 
          }
        });

      });
    }
```

Comment: But you didn't tell me how can i parse it through gson in doPost

Comment: And thank you very much for helping me .And responding to each doubt @v8-E

Comment: I didn't got what are you trying to say , this code will send your all data from JSP to Servlet , instead of JSP you can use HTML my suggestion is go for HTML instead of JSP. This code will work with JSP also.If your question is about parsing it's not required that library will do it just download `Gson Jar` and add it to build path.  Read more about Gaon, Happy Codding

Comment: To get these values use  `request.getParameter("exact name of form field you used in JSP")`

Comment: On running your code i am not getting my selected value from <select> tag in form i am actually getting the whole get request part.Your help is appreciable @-v8-E

Comment: this code will send your form Data to using `POST` method Servlet then you can use those values using `request.getParameter("exact name of form field you used in JSP")` if you want to send them reverse use first code I have given to you hope it  help. You need to do debugging to find it out what is not working for you .

Comment: I am getting [object][object] when I put alert in on ajax success

Comment: because you are sending that `itemsfood` you can send only test as response like done or completed or any other message

Comment: actually I just want to send the selected value inside the select tag to the doPost method @-v8-E

Comment: $("#mForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //var form=$(this);
    var value = $('select#item option:selected').val();
    alert(value);
    $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"gouraberClass",
     data:value,
     success:function(data)
     {
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
      
     }
     
    });
   });

Comment: and also i wanted get to see my dopost method getting data from this ajax post calling...@ v8-E .

Comment: I really like to help you but the thing is here I cant we have to follow rule,Could you please get in touch at v8sagar@gmail.com please if possible

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can remove jstl from my jsp page and can make it html.

you need to use these jquery cdn or you can use javascript directly.

Addtinaly you need to download **Gson** library to get response from servlet. 
This code will work with `get` method.

**This is how you can send** your `itemsfood` to your `html or jsp`
Modify your `doGet` method as:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<Script> scriptitems=modelDBUtil.getScriptList();
        request.setAttribute("scriptItems", scriptitems);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String itemsfood[]={"biriyani","rice"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(itemsfood);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json); 

}
```

And HTML or jsp code for that is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link
 href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link
 href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
 href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(
   function() {
    $.get("appendfile or (add your serveletName here)", function(
      responseJson) {
     var $select = $("#item");
     $select.find("option").remove();
     $.each(responseJson, function(value, key) {
      $("<option>").val(key).text(key).appendTo($select);
     });
    });
   });
</script>
<title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form name=myform id="mForm">
  <select name="item" required id="item">
   <option value="Select">select</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" id="idsubmit">Submit</button>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you help me out with a post request with ajax

Comment: Yes why not ,What you want to do with post?

Comment: yes iwant to post a form data and update in mysql database using servlet

Comment: Please help @v8-E I am unable to send to parse json in doPost method in servlet also I think I need help regarding how to send json from jsp page using ajax.Thanks for helping me

Comment: Please find second answer

Comment: Can you please send me the doPost method